# Regex for Apache

Tags: fail2ban

I would like to create a rule for Apache to block a massive logins according this type of log:

```
93.176.51.15 - - [21/Nov/2019:00:02:40 +0100] "GET /wordpress/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5485
```

What's the exactly regex that I need? I use this:

```
^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) .*/wp-login.php.*$
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

More "precise" regex would look like:

```regex
^<HOST> \S+ \S+ [^"]*"[A-Z]{3,15}\s+\S*/wp-login\.php\b
```

It is anchored (`^.+` is not an anchor), does not have catch-all's (like `.*` but especially non-greedy like `.+?`), and covers all http-methods as well as from intruder side supplied user-name (if no auth expected and web server would log it instead of `-`).

And if you have fail2ban >= 0.10 use `<ADDR>` instead of `<HOST>` (more faster, safe and precise if only IPs are logged).